# Tapestry: How to use Checkbox with Tree

Tags: checkbox, tree, tapestry

I am trying to implement a tree. I want users to be able to select leaf nodes by clicking on checkbox at each leaf nodes. But it is currently not working with the checkbox. The tree cannot expand.

Here is my tml code fragment

```
<t:zone t:id="treeZone" id="treeZone">
     <t:tree t:id="Tree" t:model="treeModel" t:node="treeNode" >
          <p:label>
                <t:if test="treeNode.leaf">
                        <input t:id="leafNode" t:type="checkbox" value="leaf" />
                        ${treeNode.label}

                    <p:else>
                         ${treeNode.label}
                    </p:else>
                </t:if>
           </p:label>
       </t:tree>
</t:zone>
```

If I take away

```
<input t:id="leafNode" t:type="checkbox" value="leaf" />
```

then the tree can expand. But I need the checkbox. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only assume that you have exceptions in your log file.

I don't think the Tree component currently supports forms and field components out of the box. To support `<t:checkbox />` and `<t:textfield />` etc inside a `<t:form />` you would need to do some magic with [FormFragment](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/FormFragment.html) and [FormInjector](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/FormInjector.html). I don't suggest trying this unless you are a tapestry guru. The code might look a little like [AjaxFormLoop](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/AjaxFormLoop.html).

I seem to remember Howard Lewis Ship (the creator of Tapestry) tweeting about using Tree and Checkbox together in Tapestry 5.4 (currently unreleased). You might want to take a look at the 5.4 source code.

If you want a quick fix, you could render an html checkbox (not the tapestry component, just a plain old `<input type="checkbox" name="..." />`). This might require you to deal with [RequestParameter](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/annotations/RequestParameter.html)s on the server side.